# While scrolling top finding a strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to animate the menu bar(fixed positioned) when its scrolled down the opacity should change to 0.6 and when scrollTop()  returns 0 its opacity should be 1.

Its working fine when I scroll down but when I scroll to  the top sometimes the code works some times its opacity remains 0.6.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
            $('.navbar').animate({opacity:0.6});
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop()  <= 0){
            $('.navbar').css('opacity','1');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 0) 
{
    $('.navbar').animate({opacity:0.6}); 
}    
else 
{ 
    $('.navbar').css('opacity','1'); 
}
```